# Debugging Javascript functions in Firebug

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

I am trying to debug legacy scripts with Firebug. As per my knowledge (Which I got yesterday) 
we use `Step over (F10)` to debug line by line and `Step into (F11)` to dig into JS function. 
But when I use `Step into` on any JS function call, it takes control to next line. I want to see what is hidden inside the function. How can we do it ?
I kept break-point inside the function and then tried `Step into` then it takes control inside the function body. But it is tedious to find each function method and set break-point.
Is there any other way to do it ? or which is the right way ?
For example :

```
 i2b2.ONT.ctrlr.FindBy = {

    clickSearchName: function() {
      // do some stuff
      i2b2.ONT.ctrlr.FindBy.doNameSearch(search_info);  // I tried Step into here
      // some more stuff
    }  

    doNameSearch: function(inSearchData) {
     // If I set break-point here then only I can debug it 
     // or it directly takes control to `// some more stuff` in `clickSearchName:function` 

    }
 }
```

PS: It also more external JS function calls.

Thanks,
Ajinkya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Step into" will step into the function if there is JS source for the function.  If not (like for `document.getElementById("foo")`, it will step over it since it doesn't have anything that it understand to step into.

If you can point us to a working example where you are having the problem (either a jsFiddle reduction of the problem or a working web page) with instruction on where the relevant code is, we can probably help more.

Judging by your code example, I'm wondering what you're trying to step into.  The line of code that starts with `clickSearchName` defines a function.  It doesn't execute it.  So, it won't go into that function until some later code actually calls `clickSearchName`.  So, perhaps you're breaking on the definition of the function and trying to step into the function when it isn't being executed.  That's just a guess though since we don't have a working example to try ourselves.

Comment: @jfiend00: As I mentioned in the example `doNameSearch` have JS source. Is there anything else we need to consider ?

Comment: @Ajinkya - See the last paragraph I added to my answer.

Comment: As per my observation (which may be wrong) `doNameSearch` is called from `clickSearchName` and I tried `Step into` on same function call.

Comment: Was someone actually calling `clickSearchName` or were you just stepping over the definition of `clickSearchName`?  Do you understand the difference between those two scenarios?  A working example of code that illustrates this problem put in a tool like jsFiddle would remove all confusion about what you're really asking. Step Into will step in.  So, there's something else wrong with the situation that you are describing to us and we need to see/understand more about your situation to know how to help you.

Comment: Yes `clickSearchName` is called from my application. I cann't create a fiddle as there are so many other things involved.

Comment: Step Into works.  The idea behind the jsFiddle is for you to isolate the smallest part of code that illustrates the problem (you can step through things in a jsFiddle too, not include everything.  Or, you can post a link to a public web page with details on where we find the troublesome code that you can't step into.  Other than that, not much else we can do but make wild guesses.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Will try to post a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line `debugger;` to your code at the place where you want to break into the debugger, it's a JavaScript keyword, which should do what you want.  Just remember to take it out when you're done debugging your code.

Comment: @rm: Thats the thing I want to avoid. There are tons of function call and I don't want to go to each function to set beakpoint or add `debugger;`. I thought `Step into` will do it.Isnt it ?